# index with leading zeros (string concatenation with numeric format)

Tags: python-3.x, list, string-formatting

How can I get this index-list, but with leading zeros ("%04d"-format)?

```
["index{}".format(i) for i in range(20)]
```

Want: "index0001", "index0002", ..

Thx & kind regards

Comment: ` ["index{:04d}".format(i) for i in range(20)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think zfill is what you need

`["index{}".format(str(i).zfill(4)) for i in range(20)]`